# Odoo: Is it possible to use the same Bank Account for multiple Contacts?

Tags: odoo

I was importing my creditor list from another system into Odoo 12 Community version and found out, that it is not possible to use the same account number for a Contact:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "res_partner_bank_unique_number"

That means, that field acc_number on res.partner.bank model must be unique?

I have some creditors, that share Bank Accounts. How to enable possibility to choose multiple Contacts for one Bank Account? Is that even possible? Is there any module for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution would be to change sql_constraints for res.partner.bank model as it was done here: https://github.com/wtaferner/odoo/commit/326727bbd7161f6c2af68009d3d9fc924772d665
to

```
_sql_constraints = [
        ('unique_number', 'unique(sanitized_acc_number, company_id, partner_id)', 'Account Number must be unique for Partner'),
    ]
```

Comment: I hope, that this will be merged to the source code of Odoo. Thank you for the feedback!